# How to Join two Queries in Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I tried to join two queries and based on it find the result. I am able to write the code in SQL. My SQL Code is

```
SELECT a.awbid, 
       m.mpscount
FROM ( select a.awbid 
       FROM awbmaster a 
       where a.batchid ='B/117/15022022' 
       and a.hubid ='117'
     ) as a 
left join ( select count('mpsid') as "mpscount" , 
                   awbid from 
                   mpsmaster m 
                   where m.batchid = 'B/117/15022022' 
                   group by "awbid"
          ) as m on a.awbid = m.awbid
```

But, I am not yet found any solution regarding the sequelize. How can I write the above SQL code in sequelize?

Comment: Maybe it's worth [taking a look here](https://fengmk2.github.io/blog/2014/10/sql-to-sequelize-mapping-chart.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can simplify this SQL query simply using a subquery to find out `mpscount`:

```sql
SELECT a.awbid,
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM mpsmaster m
   WHERE m.batchid = 'B/117/15022022'
     AND m.awbid=a.awbid ) AS mpscount
FROM awbmaster a
WHERE a.batchid ='B/117/15022022'
  AND a.hubid ='117'
```

Now if we already have both models `MpsMaster` and `AwbMaster` and a correct association between them then we can make a request something like this:

```js
const records = AwbMaster.findAll(}
  attributes: [
   'awbid',
   [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT count(*) FROM mpsmaster m WHERE m.batchid = \'B/117/15022022\' AND m.awbid=AwbMaster.awbid)'), 'mpscount']
  ]
})
```